# delete terms which contain zero post when removing terms from a post

Tags: wordpress

When removing terms from a post, delete terms which contain zero post. When updating a post, delete terms which contain zero post.

I have tried the code below, but it doesn't work:

```
add_filter('wp_remove_object_terms','delete_unused_terms');
function delete_unused_terms($term_ids, $taxonomy) {
    foreach ( $term_ids as $term_id ) {
        $term = get_term($term_id, $taxonomy);
        $term_count = $term->count;
        if ($term_count<1) {
            wp_delete_term($term_id, $taxonomy);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no `wp_remove_object_terms` filter.

But there is an action `deleted_term_relationships`;

Please, try to use

```
add_action( 'deleted_term_relationships', 'yuor_prefix_update_delete_term_if_empty', 10, 3 );

function yuor_prefix_update_delete_term_if_empty( $object_id, $term_ids, $taxonomy ) {
    wp_update_term_count( $term_ids, $taxonomy );

    foreach ( $term_ids as $term_id ) {
        $term = get_term($term_id, $taxonomy);
        $term_count = $term->count;

        if ($term_count<1) {
            wp_delete_term($term_id, $taxonomy);
        }
    }
}
```